# Dumping Source Code into a local file using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

When I use download() in CasperJS, I get a file saved in the system, but the file doesn't contain the actual source code of the webpage. It just contains a link to the remote page. How can I dump the source code of webpage into a local file using CasperJs? getHTML() is also only echoing the contents onto the terminal. How to save the contents to a file?

Comment: Maybe this link could help : http://darrendev.blogspot.fr/2013/11/saving-downloaded-files-in-slimerjs-and.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write results into a file using Casper JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826596/write-results-into-a-file-using-casper-js)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First import file system library

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

Extract html

```
var html = this.getHTML();
// or
var html = this.getPageContent();
```

Copy into a file

```
var f = fs.open('/path/to/your/file', 'w');
f.write(html);
f.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

do just: `fs.write('path/to/file', 'your string', 'w');`
in this case you don't need open and close a file